# Apple Swift version 5.7 not working on Apple Swift version 5.6.1

Tags: xcode14, swift5.7, swift5.6

We have built a binary framework built with Xcode 14.1 using Xcode 13.4.1 getting below error.

BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION ENABLED ALSO.

> this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with
> 'Apple Swift version 5.7.1 (swiftlang-5.7.1.135.3
> clang-1400.0.29.51)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version
> 5.6.1 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.66 clang-1316.0.20.12)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.

Comment: If we build Xcode 13.4.1, it's working fine